# paper.js vector slow performance

Tags: javascript, vector, paperjs

I've been trying to get this fairly simple program to work and am running into performance problems.

I'm trying to make thousands of tiny colored dots on a canvas. Creating so many new paths is slowing down my computer before I am able to get the amount that I want on the canvas, and then crashes when I try to export the canvas as an SVG. I looked into using symbols, but I need the colors of each dot to be different.

The goal is for every color and position to be completely random and unique, and to have the dots completely cover the canvas. The canvas will eventually need to be printed 55 inches by 75 inches, so I will want the circles to be of high enough resolution that they don't look pixellated when printed. This can mean either being able to export to a high enough raster resolution or to export to a vector.

I'm using paper.js because I figured that it would be best to render the dots as vector graphics so that I can print them at high quality when I need to, but is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.
the html below is everything (except for the paper.js library).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <!-- Load the Paper.js library -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/paper.js"></script>
 <!-- Define inlined PaperScript associate it with myCanvas -->
 <style type="text/css">
 html,
 body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
 }
 /* Scale canvas with resize attribute to full size */
 canvas[resize] {
  width: 550px;
  height: 750px;
  background-color: #39ff14;
 }
</style>
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
paper.install(window);
tool.fixedDistance = .1;
var layer = project.activeLayer;
function onMouseMove(event) {
 var radius = (1 * Math.random()) + .5;;
 var path = new Path.Circle({
  center: Point.random() * view.size,
  radius: radius,
  fillColor: "#000000".replace(/0/g,function(){return (~~(Math.random()*16)).toString(16);}),
 })
}
// START DOWNLOAD BUTTON &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
function downloadDataUri(options) {
 if (!options.url)
 options.url = "http://download-data-uri.appspot.com/";
 $('<form method="post" action="' + options.url
 + '" style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="filename" value="'
 + options.filename + '"/><input type="hidden" name="data" value="'
 + options.data + '"/></form>').appendTo('body').submit().remove();
}
$('#export-button').click(function() {
 var svg = project.exportSVG({ asString: true });
 downloadDataUri({
  data: 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(svg),
  filename: 'export.svg'
 });
});
// END DOWNLOAD BUTTON &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
 <input type="button" value="Download as SVG" id="export-button">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- <script src="js/scripts.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you done further investigation on this performance issue since then?